# Grouping based on start date matching the previous row's end date SQL

Tags: sql, date, netezza, gaps-and-islands

Hoping someone can help me out with this problem.

I have the following sample dataset:

| MEM_ID | CLM_ID | ADM_DT | DCHG_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 01-01-2020 | 02-01-2020 |
| 1 | 112 | 03-01-2020 | 04-01-2020 |
| 1 | 113 | 04-01-2020 | 05-01-2020 |
| 1 | 114 | 06-01-2020 | 07-01-2020 |
| 2 | 211 | 01-01-2020 | 02-01-2020 |
| 2 | 212 | 05-01-2020 | 08-01-2020 |
| 3 | 311 | 02-01-2020 | 03-01-2020 |
| 3 | 312 | 03-01-2020 | 05-01-2020 |
| 3 | 313 | 05-01-2020 | 06-01-2020 |
| 3 | 314 | 07-01-2020 | 08-01-2020 |

I am trying to create groupings based on MEM_ID. If a ADM_DT is equal to the previous DCHG_DT then the records should be grouped together

Below is the expected output:

| MEM_ID | CLM_ID | ADM_DT | DCHG_DT | GROUP_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 01-01-2020 | 02-01-2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 112 | 03-01-2020 | 04-01-2020 | 2 |
| 1 | 113 | 04-01-2020 | 05-01-2020 | 2 |
| 1 | 114 | 06-01-2020 | 07-01-2020 | 3 |
| 2 | 211 | 01-01-2020 | 02-01-2020 | 1 |
| 2 | 212 | 05-01-2020 | 08-01-2020 | 2 |
| 3 | 311 | 02-01-2020 | 03-01-2020 | 1 |
| 3 | 312 | 03-01-2020 | 05-01-2020 | 1 |
| 3 | 313 | 05-01-2020 | 06-01-2020 | 1 |
| 3 | 314 | 07-01-2020 | 08-01-2020 | 2 |

I have attempted the following:

```
select DISTINCT MEM_ID
,CLM_ID
,ADM_DT
,DCHG_DT
,CASE WHEN ADM_DT = LAG(DCHG_DT) OVER(PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ISSTART
FROM 
table
```

Which produces something like this:

| MEM_ID | CLM_ID | ADM_DT | DCHG_DT | ISSTART |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 01-01-2020 | 02-01-2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 112 | 03-01-2020 | 04-01-2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 113 | 04-01-2020 | 05-01-2020 | 0 |
| 1 | 114 | 06-01-2020 | 07-01-2020 | 1 |
| 2 | 211 | 01-01-2020 | 02-01-2020 | 1 |
| 2 | 212 | 05-01-2020 | 08-01-2020 | 1 |
| 3 | 311 | 02-01-2020 | 03-01-2020 | 1 |
| 3 | 312 | 03-01-2020 | 05-01-2020 | 0 |
| 3 | 313 | 05-01-2020 | 06-01-2020 | 0 |
| 3 | 314 | 07-01-2020 | 08-01-2020 | 1 |

I have also looked into other external sources such as https://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-query-for-overlapping-time-periods-on-sql-server.aspx

This got me pretty close but I realized that the author was using a recursive CTE and Netezza does not support that function.

Ultimately I would like to create these groupings so that i can then merge to the original table that I am using and sum values based on the assigned group for each MEM_ID.

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select MEM_ID, CLM_ID, ADM_DT, DCHG_DT,
sum(ISSTART) over(partition by MEM_ID order by ADM_DT, DCHG_DT rows unbounded preceding) as GROUP_ID from
(select MEM_ID
,CLM_ID
,ADM_DT
,DCHG_DT
,CASE WHEN ADM_DT = LAG(DCHG_DT) OVER(PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ISSTART
FROM 
table_name) t
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fede33c1cae42bfd1f88ea1e2fba5867)

Basically using your `ISSTART` in a `sum` to get the desired output.

Comment: Glad to see I was pretty close. I will try this method and vote it as an answer once I confirm that it does the exact thing I need. Thank you!