# Grouping and min max date assignments based on dates following a unique combination of values

Tags: sql, netezza, gaps-and-islands

I am having another gaps and islands problem that I am trying to solve.

I have the following sample dataset:

| MEM_ID | CLM_ID | BGN_SERV_DT | END_SERV_DT | ADM_DT | DCHG_DT | PROV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 01-01-2021 | 01-31-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 112 | 01-01-2021 | 01-28-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 113 | 01-01-2021 | 01-25-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 114 | 02-01-2021 | 02-10-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 115 | 02-11-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 116 | 02-15-2021 | 02-17-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 2 |
| 1 | 117 | 02-18-2021 | 02-25-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 3 |
| 1 | 118 | 03-18-2021 | 03-25-2021 | 02-16-2021 | 02-16-2021 | 3 |
| 2 | 211 | 01-01-2021 | 01-31-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 212 | 03-01-2021 | 03-05-2021 | 03-01-2021 | 03-01-2021 | 2 |
| 3 | 311 | 02-01-2021 | 02-08-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 1 |
| 3 | 312 | 02-08-2021 | 02-10-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 2 |

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

Based on the unique combination of a MEM_ID,PROV,and ADM_DT, I want to group the events into 1 and assign the min BGN_SERV_DT and max END_SERV_DT. I also need to group any additional events from the same MEM_ID and PROV if the DCHG_DT is the same as the ADM_DT or up to 1 day ahead.

The end result should look like this:

| MEM_ID | CLM_ID | BGN_SERV_DT | END_SERV_DT | ADM_DT | DCHG_DT | PROV | GROUP | MIN_DT | MAX_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 01-01-2021 | 01-31-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 | 01-01-2021 | 02-15-2021 |
| 1 | 112 | 01-01-2021 | 01-28-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 | 01-01-2021 | 02-15-2021 |
| 1 | 113 | 01-01-2021 | 01-25-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 | 01-01-2021 | 02-15-2021 |
| 1 | 114 | 02-01-2021 | 02-10-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 | 01-01-2021 | 02-15-2021 |
| 1 | 115 | 02-11-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 | 01-01-2021 | 02-15-2021 |
| 1 | 116 | 02-15-2021 | 02-17-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 2 | 2 | 02-15-2021 | 02-17-2021 |
| 1 | 117 | 02-18-2021 | 02-25-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 3 | 3 | 02-18-2021 | 03-25-2021 |
| 1 | 118 | 03-18-2021 | 03-25-2021 | 02-16-2021 | 02-16-2021 | 3 | 3 | 02-18-2021 | 03-25-2021 |
| 2 | 211 | 01-01-2021 | 01-31-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 | 01-01-2021 | 01-31-2021 |
| 2 | 212 | 03-01-2021 | 03-05-2021 | 03-01-2021 | 03-01-2021 | 2 | 2 | 03-01-2021 | 03-05-2021 |
| 3 | 311 | 02-01-2021 | 02-08-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 1 | 1 | 02-01-2021 | 02-08-2021 |
| 3 | 312 | 02-08-2021 | 02-10-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 02-01-2021 | 2 | 2 | 02-08-2021 | 02-10-2021 |

You will notice that some of the ADM_DT are less than the BGN_SERV_DT, that is not a data error.

In the expected output, the first 5 records for MEM_ID 1 was grouped into group 1 because it meets the criteria of having the same MEM_ID,PROV, and ADM_DT combination. Records 6 and 7 have the same MEM_ID and ADM_DT combination but different PROV, therefore they are broken into groups 2 and 3. Record 8 has the same combination of MEM_ID and PROV but the ADM_DT is different to that of Record 7. However because the ADM_DT from record 8 is within 1 day of the DCHG_DT from record 7, it is considered the same event and assigned group 3. The rest of the data points are pretty straight forward on why they are grouped the way they are.

This is a follow up to a previous question that i asked via the below link:

[Grouping based on start date matching the previous row's end date SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153713/grouping-based-on-start-date-matching-the-previous-rows-end-date-sql/71153946?noredirect=1#comment125794078_71153946)

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MEM_ID
    , PROV
    , CLM_ID
    , ADM_DT
    , DCHG_DT
    , sum(ISSTART) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT rows unbounded preceding) AS GROUP

FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT MEM_ID
        , PROV
        , CLM_ID
        , ADM_DT
        , DCHG_DT
        , CASE 
            WHEN PROV = LAG(PROV) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT)
                AND (
                        (
                        ADM_DT = LAG(DCHG_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT)
                        )
                    OR (
                        ADM_DT = LAG(DCHG_DT + 1) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT)
                        )
                    )
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END AS ISSTART
    
    FROM c1
    ) t
```

The above code, has captured most of the instances but i am unable to figure out how to add the min and max dates. I am also unsure if my case statement is correctly being used.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

### **EDIT:**

After further investigation, it appears that either my subquery to create the islands might be faulty or my sum statement isnt being calculated correctly.

I have attempted the following code change in the sum statement to see if it fixes the issue

```
SELECT DISTINCT MEM_ID
    , PROV
    , CLM_ID
    , ADM_DT
    , DCHG_DT
    , sum(ISSTART) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID,ADM_DT ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT rows unbounded preceding) AS GROUP

FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT MEM_ID
        , PROV
        , CLM_ID
        , ADM_DT
        , DCHG_DT
        , CASE 
            WHEN PROV = LAG(PROV) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT)
                AND (
                        (
                        ADM_DT = LAG(DCHG_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT)
                        )
                    OR (
                        ADM_DT = LAG(DCHG_DT + 1) OVER (PARTITION BY MEM_ID ORDER BY ADM_DT, DCHG_DT)
                        )
                    )
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END AS ISSTART
    
    FROM c1
    ) t
```

However what I end up with is the following,

| MEM_ID | CLM_ID | BGN_SERV_DT | END_SERV_DT | ADM_DT | DCHG_DT | PROV | GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 01-01-2021 | 01-31-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 112 | 01-01-2021 | 01-28-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 113 | 01-01-2021 | 01-25-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 114 | 02-01-2021 | 02-10-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 115 | 02-11-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 116 | 02-15-2021 | 02-17-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 117 | 02-18-2021 | 02-25-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 02-15-2021 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 118 | 03-18-2021 | 03-25-2021 | 02-16-2021 | 02-16-2021 | 3 | 1 |

Comment: Check your code again!

Comment: @Zakaria are you referring to the BGN_SERV_DT and END_SERV_DT not being included? if so, I wasn't sure where to add that piece. I'll assume it would be within the subquery?

Comment: @Zakaria I see i left out the ending of my subquery. Editing the code now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If everything else works fine and you just need the two columns `MIN_DT` and `MAX_DT`, then you can use the `max` and `min` window functions:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT mem_id, 
  prov, 
  clm_id, 
  adm_dt, 
  dchg_dt, 
  Sum(isstart) OVER(
    partition BY mem_id 
    ORDER BY 
      adm_dt, 
      dchg_dt rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
  ) AS GROUP, 
  Min(bgn_serv_dt) OVER(partition BY mem_id, prov, adm_dt) AS MIN_DT, 
  Max(end_serv_dt) OVER(partition BY mem_id, prov, adm_dt) AS MAX_DT 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT mem_id, 
      prov, 
      clm_id, 
      adm_dt, 
      dchg_dt, 
      bgn_serv_dt, 
      end_serv_dt, 
      CASE WHEN prov = Lag(prov) OVER(
        partition BY mem_id 
        ORDER BY 
          adm_dt, 
          dchg_dt
      ) 
      AND (
        (
          adm_dt = Lag(dchg_dt) OVER(
            partition BY mem_id 
            ORDER BY 
              adm_dt, 
              dchg_dt
          )
        ) 
        OR (
          adm_dt = Lag(dchg_dt + 1) OVER(
            partition BY mem_id 
            ORDER BY 
              adm_dt, 
              dchg_dt
          )
        )
      ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ISSTART 
    FROM 
      c1
  ) t
```

Comment: I tried this and it is not giving me the correct min and max dates due to it not being grouped by the group variable. Would changing the partition to MEM_ID and GROUP work instead?

Comment: @CCP you can try!

Comment: I tried the group partition and this did not work. I have debugged the subquery and noticed that the isstart is not populating correctly. How can i populate the isstart subquery to assign values based on the criteria mentioned in my question? Ill edit my question to reflect the code i have tried in the meantime.

Comment: @CCP i think it'd be better if you made another post with the new requirements! I'm watching the `sql` tag so I'll probably come accross it. Mention my name here if you do so so I can get a notification and I'll see if I can help!

Comment: I have created a new question titled Creating groupings based on criteria. It is basically the same dataset used in this question, but excluding the min and max date pieces.

Comment: Bookmarked it. I'll take a look tomorrow when I have time and will answer if I can solve it. Hopefully somebody else will have answered it already meanwhile ^^